# DropDownListFor multiselect Set Default Value

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a DropDownListFor that is set as a multiselect:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClaimStateIds, Model.ClaimStateList,new { @id = "claimState", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NebK9.png)

I would like the multiselect to default select the "Select all" option but I have no idea how to ahieve this.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

I have tried setting the value in JQuery:

```
$('#claimState').multiselect('selectAll');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma1EH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't provide the enough code for your dropdown list, So here I create a simply demo to show that when the page load, Dropdown list will default select `select all` option and all the options(except the `select all` option) will be selected.

```
ClaimStateList = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Select All",
                        Value = "all",
                    },
                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = "AAA",
                        Value = "1"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = "BBB",
                        Value = "2"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = "CCC",
                        Value = "3"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = "DDD",
                        Value = "4"
                    }
                }
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ClaimStateIds,Model.ClaimStateList,new { @id = "claimState", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            selectAll()
        })

        $('#claimState').change(function () {

            if ($("#claimState option[value='all']").is(':selected')) {
                selectAll();
            }
        })

        function selectAll() {
            $('#claimState option').prop('selected', true);
            $("#claimState option[value='all']").prop('selected', false);
        }
    </script>
```

Demo

[image]

From above demo, when the page load, It will default select all the options(except select all).